# Is it possible to parameterize these SQL queries C#

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a easy way to parameterize these queries, I've had a look at quite a few different sites but can't find what I want

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET" && TableName != null)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM " + TableName;

            if (SearchID != null && Regex.IsMatch(SearchID, @"^\d+$"))
            {
                cmd.CommandText += " WHERE " + TableName + "ID Like '%" + SearchID + "%'";
            }
            else if (SearchName != null)
            {
                cmd.CommandText += " WHERE " + TableName + "Name LIKE '%" + SearchName.Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
            }
            if (ID != null)
            {
                cmd.CommandText += " WHERE " + TableName + "ID = " + ID + "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `ID` a text or numeric column?

Comment: You can't parameterize table names.

Comment: No, not with table or column names. Only values

Comment: if cmd is an SQLCommandObject?

Answer (score 1):

You can write any sql query written used string concatenations as a sql parameterized query and you should opt the last one, since it is the most secure way (You avoid sql injections):

Change this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM " + TableName;


if (SearchID != null && Regex.IsMatch(SearchID, @"^\d+$"))
{
    cmd.CommandText += " WHERE " + TableName + "ID Like '%" + SearchID + "%'";
}
```

To this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM @TableName";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", TableName);

if (SearchID != null && Regex.IsMatch(SearchID, @"^\d+$"))
{
    cmd.CommandText += " WHERE ID Like %@SearchID%";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchID",SearchID);
}
```

You have to make the same for the rest `if` statements.

**Note** However I have to confess that I have never seen to pass a parameter the name of the Table.